# Build Tetragon without docker

Tags: cilium

Is it possible to build Tetragon without docker? I am trying to build non image target "make tetragon" but still it is trying to access docker. I can't use docker due to some limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install Tetragon as a systemd service without requiring Docker: https://tetragon.io/docs/installation/package/.

The steps are as follows, for version v1.0.0 on amd64:

```
curl -LO https://github.com/cilium/tetragon/releases/download/v1.0.0/tetragon-v1.0.0-amd64.tar.gz
tar -xvf tetragon-v1.0.0-amd64.tar.gz
cd tetragon-v1.0.0-amd64/
./install.sh
```

You can then view the status of the systemd service as usual:

```
systemctl status tetragon
```